# Error al subir archivo CSV mac y/o windows con PHP

Tags: php

Como puedo hacer para que mi código pueda reconocer tanto archivos CSV Mac, como también CSV windows al subir archivo CSV a mi base de datos en mysql con PHP.

Tengo el siguiente código.

El problema es que cuando subo un archivo CSV guardado en mac tengo que ponerle la linea:
$l = iconv('MACINTOSH', 'utf-8', $l);

Pero cuando subo un archivo CSV de windows no me funciona y debo cambiar esa misma linea a:
$l = mb_convert_encoding($l, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

```
$l = trim($record);
            if (!empty($l)) {
                if (!mb_check_encoding($l, 'UTF-8')) {
                    if (mb_check_encoding($l, 'ISO-8859-1')) {
                        
                        $l = iconv('MACINTOSH', 'utf-8', $l);

                        //$l = iconv("UTF8-8", "MACINTOSH", $l);
                        $search = array("ç", "‡", "ƒ", "Ž", "ê", "’", "î", "—", "ò", "œ", "„", "–");
                        $replace = array("Á", "á", "É", "é", "Í", "í", "Ó", "ó", "Ú", "ú", "Ñ", "ñ");
                        //$l = str_replace($search, $replace, $l);
                        \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('logger')->log("STR_REPLACE ".json_encode($l));
                        $flag = false;
                        
                        foreach($search as $value){
                            $pos = strpos($l, $value);
                            
                            if($pos != false){
                                $flag = true;
                            }else{
                                $flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if($flag === true){
                            \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('logger')->log("ENCUENTRA");
                        }else{
                            \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('logger')->log("NO ENCUENTRA");
                        }
```

Como puedo hacer para que me funcione para ambos archivos?

Cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Has intentado con `mb_detect_encoding()`?

Comment: Hola @Sal no he intentado con eso, como podría aplicarlo en mi código?